# OpenCV best method to handle this task (Object detection, segregation, auto rotate)

Tags: opencv, object, rotation, detection

What is the best way to approach this project with OpenCV? Should I be using template matching or other methods? The goal here is to be able to detect and match a "master" label in the image first and then save each one of them to individual image files. The other issue is that some of the labels are rotated.

I would appreciate any expert advice on how to go about doing this task.

Thanks in advance.

Andy

[image: Sample image]

Comment: We're not going to download rar files. Sorry :-( Please include your code and/or images in the actual question. This question is also very broad. Have you already started on trying to solve this? It's generally encouraged that you make a start yourself first, and then try to ask a question is you get stuck somewhere, rather than ask very broad "how do I fix this?"-questions.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I just need to know what approach I should take with OpenCV and what commands to use. I am fairly new with OpenCV and I have been given recommendations from Haar to Template matching. I was hoping to get some expert advice on how to proceed instead of reinventing the wheel from scratch when someone has already attempted something like this. Thanks for the response.